# Crout's decomposition for pentadiagonal matrices.

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to find an efficient algorithm for computing the LU decomposition of Pentadiagonal matrices using Crout's method. We have $A=LU$, where $L$ is lower diagonal, and $U$ is upper diagonal with entries on the main diagonal being $1$.

My working was that the $k^{\text{th}}$  element of the first row of $A$ is of the form $L_{R_1} U_{C_k}$ where $L_{R_1}$ is the first row of $L$ and $U_{C_k}$ is the $k^{\text{th}}$ column of $U$, then, $U_{C_{k}}=0$ for $k\ge 4$ due to the structure of a pentadiagonal matrix, similarly, $L_{R_k}=0$ for $k \ge 4$. This would leave only six elements in both $L$ and $U$, and should give us an efficient way to calculate the LU decomposition of $A$.

I am not really sure whether my working is correct, if anyone could shed some light on this, that would be of great help.